# Nexus 6p runs with normal size layout instead of large

Tags: android, android-studio, adaptive-design, nexus-6p

[image]

Android Studio shows Nexus 6P size name as "large" but still the device runs with "normal" layout. My normal layout is appropriate for actually normal devices and Nexus 6P is actually large enough to work with "large" layouts. How to fix this ?

Comment: layout-600sw for 6inch and above  screen
layout-720sw for 10inch and above  screen

Comment: What layouts are you using? Nexus 6p is only 5.7", so it's not that much actually. Are you using the layouts with the suffixes of -w600dp or -w720dp or something? I don't think Nexus 6p has the width of 600dp.

Comment: Please show the contents of your res directory, in particular the layouts subdirectory

Comment: I am using layout , layout-small , layout-large , layout-xlarge. My real question is, what specifier is to be used for Nexus 6P and similar devices which fit neither of the ones I am already using .

Comment: It actually fits in the small layout if it does not fit in the large one :)

Comment: I have set the small layout for actually small devices. If Nexus 6P uses small layout everything would look tiny. So there is no specifier between normal and large or large and xlarge which nexus 6P uses ? What are the tags 600sw or 720sw used for ?